tomcat process memory is higher than the jvm heap memory
We are running a SpringBoot application in tomcat 9.x with OpenJDK11. This application is hosted on a VM.
We have been observing high memory utilization of the tomcat process in dynatrace. "Memory Usage" graph of the process is showing 5.3gb while the heap memory usage is 2 gb. Can someone help me where the remaining 3.3gb memory is used?
Note: tomcat profile contains only one application running in it. We are using Xms as 1024m and Xmx as 4096.
1
]2
